Accessibility - How to Programmatically Shift Screen Reader Focus to a Specific Widget in Flutter?
I am working on a Flutter project and incorporating accessibility features within a quiz.
My question:
How can I ensure that after a user selects an answer, the screen reader automatically focuses back on the question when the next question loads?
I have this sample code:
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizPage({super.key});

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  int _currentQuestionIndex = 0;
  late FocusNode _questionFocusNode;

  final List<Map<String, Object>> _questions = [
    {
      'question': 'What color is the sky?',
      'answers': ['Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow'],
      'correctAnswer': 0,
    },
    {
      'question': 'How many planets are in the solar system?',
      'answers': ['7', '8', '9'],
      'correctAnswer': 1,
    },
    {
      'question': 'Which is the largest ocean in the world?',
      'answers': ['Atlantic Ocean', 'Indian Ocean', 'Pacific Ocean'],
      'correctAnswer': 2,
    },
    {
      'question': 'What is the capital of France?',
      'answers': ['Berlin', 'Madrid', 'Paris'],
      'correctAnswer': 2,
    },
  ];

  void _answerQuestion(int selectedAnswerIndex) {
    if (selectedAnswerIndex ==
        _questions[_currentQuestionIndex]['correctAnswer']) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Correct answer!')),
      );
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(content: Text('Wrong answer!')),
      );
    }

    setState(() {
      if (_currentQuestionIndex < _questions.length - 1) {
        _currentQuestionIndex++;
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(content: Text('The quiz is finished!')),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Exam'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Semantics(
              label: 'Frage ${_currentQuestionIndex + 1}',
              child: Text(
                _questions[_currentQuestionIndex]['question'] as String,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            ...(_questions[_currentQuestionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map((entry) {
              int index = entry.key;
              String answer = entry.value;
              return Semantics(
                label: 'Option ${entry.key + 1}: $answer',
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _answerQuestion(index),
                  child: Text(answer),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

